# How can I get a Discord Context Object from the on_message event?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im currently working on a bot, actually for a bit longer now, always with commands. The argument for a command is always a Context Object:

```
@client.command
async def test(context):
    message = context.message
```

So I've build my whole system around the Context Object. Now I wanted to use the on_message event, but instead of passing a Context Object, in this case, Discord passes a message Object:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
```

**How can I get the Context Objext using the message Object?**

Comment: The `message` and `context` parameters are completely different from each other. You can't get context from message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = await client.get_context(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

By using asynchronous function, have you used `await` in functions,

```
@client.command
async def test(context):
    message = context.message
    #This will be stored in context which must be retrieved

@client.event
async def on_message(Message):
    ctx = await client.get_context(Message)
    #Do whatever you want
```