# discord.py call @client.command() from @client.event

Tags: discord.py

I have a function which is `@client.command()`:

```
@client.command()
async def warn(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    add_warning_points(member)
    await ctx.send(f'Warned {member.mention} for {reason}')
```

Now, I want to call it from `on_message()`:

```
@client.event
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def on_message(message):
    for word in fwords:
        if word in message.content.lower():
            print("WARNING: Filtered word")
            await warn() # I want to call warn() here
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

However, i can't call `warn()` in that way because it requires `ctx` but `ctx` doesn't exist in `@client.event` function

Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a Discord Context Object from the on\_message event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63819901/how-can-i-get-a-discord-context-object-from-the-on-message-event)

Comment: I wouldn't try to call the actual command itself, but if you do need to, see the dupe target. It would probably be better to make a `warn_member` that does the actually logic, with a `warn` and `on_message` that call that.